# How JAXB mapping is done in Spring boot SOAP webservices

Tags: soap, spring-ws

I have a question on JAXB mapping using org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotations.

I was able to generate Java domain object with provided *.xsd. The thing is after I define my endpoint with
@PayloadRoot, I have to wrap my request and response as below to successfully trigger the method and return a result:

@PayloadRoot( localPart = "PmtAuthAddRequest",
namespace = "http://*com/emb/webseries")
@ResponsePayload
public JAXBElement billPayment(@RequestPayload JAXBElement var1){

```
 PmtAuthAddResponseType response=billPaymentHandler.execute(var1.getValue());

 return of.createPmtAuthAddResponse(response);  // Used ObjectFactory to create JAXBElement.
```

}`

`

From all the tutorial I see, they dont need to wrap it as JAXBElement to return the correct type, but the below code does not work for me:

```
`
`@PayloadRoot( localPart = "PmtAuthAddRequest",
         namespace = "http://*com/emb/webseries")
 @ResponsePayload
 public PmtAuthAddResponseType billPayment(@RequestPayload PmtAuthAddRequestType> var1){

     PmtAuthAddResponseType response=billPaymentHandler.execute(var1.getValue());

     return response; 
}`

`
```

Do you guys know why? How can I resolve this? Thanks

I tried without wrapping it as JAXBElement, but soap UI return with error message:

```
`no adapter for endpoint [public com.*.*.*.webseries.billpay.CustPayee50InqResponseType com.*.Endpoint.InquirePayeeEndpoint.inquirepayees(com.*.*.*.webseries.billpay.CustPayee50InqRequestType) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring>
  `
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually solved my own question....

The way to do it is to add @XmlRootElement under generated Java class from JAXB2 with below to correctly mapping:

@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://*.*.*/emb/webseries",name = "CustPayee50InqRequest")

The name should match with the localPart provided name from @PayloadRoot.

Added both for request and response makes it work for me